# xslt_create() with PHP5

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am currently trying to display a RSS feed in a PHP page, but it seems to have a problem between the xslt_create() function and PHP5.

```
<?php

$xh = xslt_create();

$file=fopen(WEB_DIR . 'assets/_xml/rss.xml','r');
$xml=fread($file,16384);
fclose($file);

$file=fopen(WEB_DIR . 'assets/_xml/rss.xslt','r');
$xsl=fread($file,16384);
fclose($file);

$arguments = array(
  '/_xml' => $xml,
  '/_xsl' => $xsl
  );

$result = xslt_process($xh, 'arg:/_xml', 'arg:/_xsl', NULL, $arguments);

xslt_free($xh);

print "$result";
?>
```

I get the error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function xslt_create() in

What do I have to do to correct this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xslt_create` only exists in PHP 4 - as this approach to parsing XML was removed in PHP 5.

As such, I'd recommend updating your code to use one of the current PHP 5 approaches as listed within the [XML Manipulation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) section of the manual. (The [XSL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) extension provides a [XSLTProcessor class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php) that is probably the nearest direct equivalent.)